# 3 domains, 1 wordpress install, redirecting and changing domains on live site

Tags: php, redirect, htaccess, installation, domain

**UPDATED & SIMPLIFIED:**

I have one Wordpress install at Host #1 with a domain (Domain-A) at Host #2. Domain-A was used for the WP install.

I have Domain-B & Domain-C at Host #3.

I need Domain-B & Domain-C to now point to the Wordpress site at Host #1, and the original WP domain (Domain-A) to point to Domain-C.

How would I handle the redirects and make the proper changes in Wordpress and/or the htaccess to make everything resolve properly?

Answer (score 0):

It's still confusing a little bit but definitely not best to resolve this with WordPress.

Many hosting providers offer you to set domain redirect right in their control panel and often that's the easiest to manage and also not require you to have web hosting with them (domain control is enough).

If I understand your situation correctly, you want to:

1. Redirect Domain-A to Domain-C
2. Redirect Domain-B to Domain-C
3. Set A record (IP address) of Domain-C to Hosting provider #1

Comment: I've setup the Domain-C to point to the nameservers for the WP site, but the WP site was setup using Domain-A in the "General Settings" in the WP dashboard. I want the site to resolve to Domain-C now. Do I change both the "WordPress Address (URL)" and the "Site Address (URL)" to Domain-C, or do I change only the Site Address since it was originally setup using Domain-A? This is the part that's really confusing me, and I'm worried about messing up a setting that will effectively lock me out of WP.

Comment: Do you have access to database via Control Panel or software like phpMyAdmin? You can always change the WordPress Address and Site Address later in wp_options. And you want to set them to now use Domain-C. You can also find desktop clients that connects to database via db hostname, db name, db user, and db password.

Comment: I do have access to the database and I thought about that, but I wasn't sure if updating through the dashboard would change other settings that I didn't know about. If those are the only two settings I need to worry about, then I'll be good.

Comment: You will have to deal with changing absolute URLs if you ever used them in pages, posts, widget, etc. If you used them, convert then into root relative URLs so you never have to deal with it again.

Also watch out for theme options if you uploaded any logo. You just need to select it again from media library.

Some theme has built-in image caching that you need to clear off as well because it cached old URL.